# heatmap python dash nested with same axis

Tags: python, plotly

I would like to display a matrix of counts 'pass , fail, not measured' . I could do that in three heatmaps plots. Is it possible to have one plot combining three?

I have tried the following:

```
import plotly.offline as pyo
import plotly.graph_objs as go

p = [[1, 20, 30, 50, 1], [20, 1, 60, 80, 30], [30, 60, 1, 10, 20]]
f = [[1, 2, 3, 1, 1], [1, 1, 6, 8, 3], [3, 6, 1, 1, 2]]
nm = [[0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]

x = ['Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday']
y = ['Morning', 'Afternoon', 'Evening']

data =[]
trace1  = go.Heatmap(x=x, y=y , z=p , name='pass')
trace2  = go.Heatmap(x=x, y=y , z=f,  name='fail')
trace3  = go.Heatmap(x=x, y=y , z=nm, name='not measured')

data.append(trace1)
data.append(trace2)
data.append(trace3)

fig = go.Figure(data=data)
fig.show()
```

What i would like is to have a matrix where each cell in the matrix have 3 cells for each x, y axis to represents pass , fail and not measured. Is heatmap the correct way? Bar chart is a good way to represent this data, but i would like to display data in very compact way.

[image: A sample output]

Regards

Comment: can you provide a sketch or example of what you'd like the output to look like?

Answer (score 0):

If what you're looking for really matches the structure of your provided table, you can get where you want using tables. Even with colors to represent the size og the groups of pass, fail and not measured.

**Plot:**

[image]

**Code:**

```
# imports
from plotly.subplots import make_subplots
import plotly.graph_objects as go
from plotly.colors import n_colors
import numpy as np
np.random.seed(1)
import pandas as pd
import re

# color scales
colors_a = n_colors('rgb(200, 255, 200)', 'rgb(0, 200, 0)', 9, colortype='rgb')
colors_b =n_colors('rgb(255, 200, 200)', 'rgb(200, 0, 0)', 9, colortype='rgb')
colors_c = n_colors('rgb(160, 160, 160)', 'rgb(255, 255, 255)', 9, colortype='rgb')

# data
a = np.random.randint(low=0, high=9, size=3)
b = np.random.randint(low=0, high=9, size=3)
c = np.random.randint(low=0, high=9, size=3)

#subplot setup
fig = make_subplots(
    rows=1, cols=4,
    shared_yaxes=True,
    horizontal_spacing=0.005,
    specs=[[{"type": "table"}, {"type": "table"}, {"type": "table"}, {"type": "table"}]]
)

# table template
tbl = go.Table(
              header=dict(
                #values=['<b>Tbl1</b>', '<b>Tbl1</b>', '<b>Tbl1</b>'],
                line_color='white', fill_color='white',
                #align='center',font=dict(color='black', size=8)
              ),
              cells=dict(
                values=[a, b, c],
                line_color=[np.array(colors_a)[a],np.array(colors_b)[b], np.array(colors_c)[c]],
                fill_color=[np.array(colors_a)[a],np.array(colors_b)[b], np.array(colors_c)[c]],
                align='center', font=dict(color='black', size=11)
                ))

# a single extra table to show rownames for Tests
tbl2=go.Table(header=dict(
                #values=['<b>Tbl1</b>', '<b>Tbl1</b>', '<b>Tbl1</b>'],
                line_color='white', fill_color='white',
                #align='center',font=dict(color='black', size=8)
              ),
              cells=dict(
                values=[['Test1', 'Test2', 'Test3']],
                  line_color='white', fill_color='white',
                #line_color=[np.array(colors_a)[a],np.array(colors_b)[b], np.array(colors_c)[c]],
                #fill_color=[np.array(colors_a)[a],np.array(colors_b)[b], np.array(colors_c)[c]],
                align='right', font=dict(color='black', size=11)
                ))

# include tables:
fig.add_trace(
   go.Table(tbl2),
    row=1, col=1
)

fig.add_trace(
   go.Table(tbl),
    row=1, col=2
)

fig.add_trace(
   go.Table(tbl),
    row=1, col=3
)

fig.add_trace(
   go.Table(tbl),
    row=1, col=4
)

fig.update_layout(
    height=800,
    showlegend=False,
    title_text="Test results",
)


fig.update_layout(
    annotations=[
        go.layout.Annotation(text="Project A",
                                showarrow=False,
                                xref="paper",
                                yref="paper",
                                x=0.32,
                                y=1.005,
                                font=dict(family="sans serif", size=12, color="Blue")
                               ),

        go.layout.Annotation(text="Project B",
                                showarrow=False,
                                xref="paper",
                                yref="paper",
                                x=0.62,
                                y=1.005,
                                font=dict(family="sans serif", size=12, color="Blue")
                               ),

        go.layout.Annotation(text="Project C",
                                showarrow=False,
                                xref="paper",
                                yref="paper",
                                #x=0.91,
                                x=0.91,
                                y=1.005,
                               font=dict(family="sans serif", size=12, color="Blue")
                            )
    ]
)


fig.show()
```